# DNS delegation without changing WHOIS

Tags: domain-name-system, whois, delegation

I am hosting several domains on my own nameservers. Some I'd like to use with a third party webhosting provider that asked me to move the domain over to them as they don't support external nameservers. Is it strictly necessary to update the WHOIS record or could I change the records on my nameserver and point it at theirs?

Regards,
HC

Answer (score 3):

If your web hosting company can't cope with the DNS being on someone else's name servers, get a better web host!

There's absolutely no reason why the web host should have to manage your DNS, they're independent functions.

However if you decide that you do wish to have them manage it, you *will* have to change the registered name servers with your registrar, and that's what'll appear in the `whois`.  You can't just point at them from your own name server.

Answer (score 1):

It would be your SOA record for the domain, which is at the registrar for most folks.